# Can emacsclient eval /run a file

Tags: emacsclient

Just a quick question,

Can emacsclient evaluate/run Elisp code from a given file, or even better, from stdin?

Comment: Don't have a clue where to start really.

Answer (score 3):

[Emacsclient](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html) has the `--eval` (same as `-e`) option, so

```
emacsclient --eval '(load "my-file.el")'
```

will read and evaluate the file `"my-file.el"`.

I don't think Emacs has access to the `emacsclient`'s stdin, but you can do something like

```
cat <<EOF > my-file.el
```

and let user enter the lisp form terminated by `EOF` on a otherwise blank like, then pass `"my-file.el"` to `load` and remove the file.